# Shell does not throw any error for the below code

Tags: python-3.x

```
#Function sum

def sum(arg1, arg2):
    sum = arg1 + arg2
    print("Total Value is:", sum)
    return

#Now you call sum as a function

sum = (10, 20)
```

---

Why it does not throw any error message or what mistake I'm doing?

Comment: What is the problem if there is no error message?

Comment: Your code is currently *replacing* the sum function with a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #Now you call sum as a function
>
> sum = (10, 20)
> ```

Uh... no. That's not what that does.

```
sum(10, 20)
```